# Nsolve rantz not possible to plot

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a problem to plot a solution of a system of equotations in Mathematica. My system of equotations has two variables (s12 and t). It's not possible to solve it explicitly (s12:=f(t)), but I am able to get a solution for each positive t. But what I want, is a plot with t on the x-achses and s12(t) on the y-achses.

My best gues is that since I get the single solution always with the comment 
"`*Solve::ratnz: Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients. The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact system and numericizing the result*`" this doesn not work with infinite solution for mathematica.

I might have to surpress this warning or does anyone has another idea?. I only need a rough plot.

The problem is as follows:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
cinv1 = 40;
cinv2 = 4;
cinv3 = 3;
h2 = 1.4;
h3 = 1.2;
alpha = 0.04;
z = 20;
p = 0.06;
cop1 = 0;
cop2 = 1;
cop3 = 1.5;
l2 = 0.1;
l3 = 0.17;
teta2 = 0.19;
teta3 = 0.1;
co2 = -0.1;

smax = 40;
c = 1;

Plot[Solve[{s12 == ((cinv1 - 
         cinv2) + ((cinv2 - cinv3)*((s12 teta2)/(
          Sqrt[ (teta2 - teta3)] Sqrt[
           c s12^2 teta2 - (2 alpha z)/c]))))/((1/(teta2 - 
           teta3))*((teta2*cop3 - teta3*cop2) + (teta2*h3*l3*E^(p*t) -
            teta3*h2*l2*E^(p*t)))), s12 > 0}, s12, Reals], {t, 0, 10}]
```

As already said, when I use a specific t, I get a solution, otherwise I receive the message as follows:

```
"*Solve::ratnz: Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients. The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact system and numericizing the result*"
"*Solve::ratnz: Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients. The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact system and numericizing the result*"
"*Solve::ratnz: Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients. The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact system and numericizing the result*"
*"General::stop: "Further output of \!\(\*
StyleBox[
RowBox[{\"Solve\", \"::\", \"ratnz\"}], \"MessageName\"]\) will be suppressed during this calculation""*
```

Thanks a lot for your help,
Andreas

Answer (score 0):

The system has 4 solutions, 3 of them positive in the range of interest:

```
s2 = Solve[{s12 - ((cinv1 - cinv2) + ((cinv2 - cinv3) ((s12 teta2)/
          (Sqrt[(teta2 - teta3)] Sqrt[c s12^2 teta2 - (2 alpha z)/c]))))/
           ((1/(teta2 - teta3))*((teta2*cop3 - teta3*cop2) + 
           (teta2*h3*l3*E^(p*t) - teta3*h2*l2*E^(p*t))))} == 0, s12];
Plot[s12 /. s2 , {t, 0, 59}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works. Though, I am still a  bit surprised why I have to arrange it this way. Do you see a possibility to choose a specific curve e.g., [[1]]?

Comment: @user1426522 `Plot[s12 /. s2[[1]], {t, 0, 57}]`

Comment: @user1426522 The problem is not the reordering, but removing the `"Reals"` and the `s12>0` parts. Mma does not know if those conditions are met until you specify `t`

Comment: Thanks. This makes senses and helped and helps a lot. To make it a bit more complicated I would like to poste a follow-up question. Hopefully you can help me with that as well.
The current value for z is not the right one. The right one is rather in the range of 600-900. When I increase z, the "triangle" in the graph becomes smaller and smaller and will dissapear at a certain value z. When I put in the right value, no graph shows, but if I insert discrete exemplary values for t I get reasonable result. Do you have an idea? Thanks a alot, Andreas

Answer (score -1):

Important fact to add:

The proposed solution above is correct, but it uses complex numbers to solve. The graph in the solution above shows only the real part of the complex number. This might lead to some confusion as it did to me.

Though, there is a solution with solely real numbers. Since Mathematica cannot solve the equotation in a "continous way" with real numbers, I finally did a three step approach:

1. I solved the equotation at discrete points in time
2. I plotted the solution with ListLinePlot.
3. I used Interpolation[] to allow for rough detection of intresections with other curves

   `a = Table[NSolve[{s12 - ((cinv1 - cinv2) + 
       ((cinv2 - cinv3)*((s12 teta2)/(\[Sqrt] (teta2 - teta3)
       \[Sqrt](c s12^2 teta2 - (2 alpha z)/c)))))/
       ((1/(teta2 - teta3))*((teta2*cop3 -teta3*cop2) + (teta2*h3*l3*E^(p*t) - 
                  teta3*h2*l2*E^(p*t)))) == 0}, s12][[1]], {t, 0, 100}];`

   `b = Table[t, {t, 0, 100}];`

   ```
   f1a = s12 /. a;

   f1 = Transpose[{b, f1a}];

   ceiling1 = ListLinePlot[{f1},
   PlotRange -> {{0, 20}, {0, 40}},PlotStyle -> {Black, Dotted, Thickness[0.003]}];
   ```

In a next step I also needed to find the intersection of multiple curves created that way. To get a **rough** estimate, I did the following:

```
curve1 = Interpolation[f1];
intersec2a = FindRoot[curve1[x2] - t12[x2, l2], {x2, 0}];
intersec2 = x2 /. intersec2a;
```

Hope this helps